# ¿Como puedo imprimir el response en el boton?

Tags: reactjs, axios, response

Hice una peticion en react.js el consumo lo hace a un API privada y si hace la peticion pero el response que arroja tengo que imprimirlo en un boton con un alert pero en vez de imprimir el response imprime la funcion

Adjunto codigo de la peticion

```
import axios from 'axios';

   var config = {
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/api/',
  'mode': 'no-cors',
 headers: { 
'Authorization': 'Basic 
',
'origin':'x-requested-with',
'CORS':'Acces-Controll-Allow-Origin : *',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, Authorization, Origin, 
 Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control- 
Request- 
 Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
},
};



  function Get(){

axios(config)
 .then(function (response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

  })
    .catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
 }



  Get();


export default Get
```

el consumo del API si lo hace y lo muestra en la consola pero eso que muestra en la consola tengo
que mostrarla en el boton

Adjunto codigo del boton

```
  import './boton.css';
  import React from 'react';
  import Get from '../lib/Get';


 class Boton extends React.Component{

 handleClick(){
    alert(Get)
 } 



  render(){
    return(
    <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleClick} className='continuar'>continuar</button>  
    )
  }
  }
   export default Boton
```

Cómo tendría que guardar o que tendría que hacer en la petición y en el botón para que imprima el response de consola

Comment: Primero que nada, tu función `Get` no devuelve ningún valor (no hay un `return`). Segundo, estás llamando a `alert` y le estás enviando como parámetro una función y no la ejecución de una función. Por lo que por un lado debes escribir `alert(Get())` <- Con paréntesis en el `Get()`. Esto te va a mostrar un `alert` con `undefined` ya que `Get()` no devuelve ningún valor.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta Andres

Lo que estas imprimiendo es la funcion y no la estas ejecutando para mostrar su resultado.

```
    async function Get() {
       return axios(config)
         .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            return JSON.stringify(response.data)
          })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
           return "ERROR"
          });
     },
```

y luego en el componente App llamaria a mi funcion Get

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    alert(await Get());
  };
```